# Is there a REPL shell for perl6/raku?

Tags: read-eval-print-loop, raku

I know I can use `perl6` without arguments to start a minimal REPL shell, but I'm missing tab completion, readline capabilities, object inspection, etc..., so I'm wondering if there's a nicer REPL shell, like IPython for Python or `Reply` for Perl 5.

When running `perl6`, I get the following warning:

```
$ perl6
I ran into a problem while trying to set up REPL completions:
Continuing without tab completions
```

But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: `panda install Linenoise` or plain old `rlwrap perl6` is what's currently available; there's some initial work on a [Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/timo/iperl6kernel)

Comment: I've installed `Readline` (via `panda install Readline`) and that gave `perl6` readline powers, which is nice, but no tab completion yet.

Answer (score 8):

The Perl6 REPL hasn't quite caught up to all the competition. But aside from just using `rlwrap perl6`, there *are* some related modules such as

- [Linenoise](https://github.com/hoelzro/p6-linenoise)
- [Readline](https://github.com/drforr/perl6-readline)
- [LREP](https://github.com/awwaiid/p6-lrep)

Depending on what you're looking for, [Debugger::UI::CommandLine](https://github.com/jnthn/rakudo-debugger) might also be of interest (a corresponding binary `perl6-debug` or `perl6-debug-m` should already have been installed by Rakudo).

A [Jupyter kernel](https://github.com/timo/iperl6kernel) has also seen some initial commits.

Comment: That jupyter kernel project seems to be no longer active (no commits the last 2 years), but there is a [newer project](https://github.com/bduggan/p6-jupyter-kernel) started last year that seems to be very active.